# Error during go build/run execution

Tags: go

I've created a simple go script: https://gist.github.com/kbl/86ed3b2112eb80522949f0ce574a04e3

It's fetching some xml from the internet and then starts X goroutines. The X depends on file content. In my case it was 1700 goroutines.

My first execution finished with:

```
$ go run mathandel1.go 
2018/01/27 14:19:37 Get https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/162152?pricehistory=1&stats=1: dial tcp 72.233.16.130:443: socket: too many open files
2018/01/27 14:19:37 Get https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/148517?pricehistory=1&stats=1: dial tcp 72.233.16.130:443: socket: too many open files
exit status 1
```

I've tried to increase `ulimit` to 2048.

Now I'm getting different error, script is the same thou:

```
$ go build mathandel1.go 
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: flushing $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/a.out: write $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/a.out: file too large
```

What is causing that error? How can I fix that?

Comment: Use a pool of goroutines to issue the requests instead of one goroutine per request.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527948/too-many-open-files-when-making-http-requests and others for info on how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran `ulimit 2048` which changed the maximum file size.

From `man bash(1)`, `ulimit` section:

> If no option is given, then -f is assumed.

This means that you now set the maximum file size to `2048` bytes, that's probably not enough for.... anything.

I'm guessing you meant to change the limit for number of open file descriptors. For this, you want to run:

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

As for the original error (before changing the maximum file size), you're launching 1700 goroutines, each performing a http get. Each creates a connection, using a tcp socket. These are covered by the open file descriptor limit.

Instead, you should be limiting the number of concurrent downloads. This can be done with a simple [worker pool](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) pattern.

Comment: I've run both `ulimit -f X` and `ulimit X` ;). Thanks, for clarification. Maybe you could also review the script, to earn that accepted answer? ;)

Comment: There are 1750 items in the geek list, so you're launching 1750 goroutines each performing an http get each using a tcp socket. And all of those are being launched almost at the same time (probably faster than the first `get` returns anyway). The default file descriptor limit is 1024. You should rate limit your downloads.

Comment: Is there any convinient way to throtle the running gorutines? Let's assume that I'd like to start 1kk of them and have always at most 1k running.